# Wordpress - Permalinks and folders (.htaccess ?)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a Wordpress website with permalinks with post name. Now I have a new template on a specific page that uses files from exactly the same url path, and I can't change that.
How can I make Wordpress access my requested page (example.com/meniu/) and ignore the folder name with same name? (example.com/menu/swf/)

Thank you!

This is my .htaccess. How can I add exclusions?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /club/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /club/index.php [L] 

</IfModule>
```

Comment: TBH I do not understand what is required to be done. can you rephrase your question or explain a bit better, please?

Comment: I have a page in Wordpress called "menu". On the server I have a folder called "menu". Now, Appache gives me the content of the folder instead of the wordpress page, witch is made with permalinks htaccess made by wordpress.

Comment: Show your current .htaccess -- the rule needs to be modified in order to allow such "exclusion". But ideally it will be better to rename that folder ... or change post name/permalink.

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /club/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /club/index.php [L]
</IfModule>` This is my .htaccess. How can I add exclusions?

Comment: This is my .htaccess. How can I add exclusions?

Comment: Can you please update your question instead -- it's difficult to run trough in such format (all in one line), thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prepend another rule to exclude only that directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/menu
RewriteRule . /club/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /club/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check this soon. I managed to solve this problem with a directory and a index.php file where I included the wp-load file, after that the theme header and footer and after that the embeded flash file. Thank you very much and I'm sure that I will need this soon!